# Получение браузера пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте!
В одном из источников [источников](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/3.7.php) для получения браузера пользователя, в технологии **ASP.NET MVC 5** используется свойство **Request** объекта **HttpContext**. Но свойства **Browser**, как показано в примере, там нет.
Вот пример кода из [источника](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/3.7.php)

```
public string Index() {
   string browser = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
   string user_agent = HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
   string url = HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
   string ip = HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
   string referrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "" : HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
   return "<p>Browser: " + browser + "</p><p>User-Agent: " + user_agent + "</p><p>Url запроса: " + url +
       "</p><p>Реферер: " + referrer + "</p><p>IP-адрес: " + ip + "</p>";
  }
```

Мой вариант контроллера

```
public IActionResult Index() {
   string browser1 = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
   //или
   string browser2 = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Browser.Browser;
   return View();
  }
```

Возможно нужно подключить какой-то пакет или этот вариант устарел или есть другой способ? Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, напишите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ASP.NET Core данный функционал пока отсутствует.

Дело в том, что ASP.NET Core был отвязан от "взрослого" ASP.NET, который детектировал браузер клиента на основе [специальных файлов `*.browser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122(v=vs.100).aspx), расположенных в каталоге `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers\`.

Сопоставляя заголовок `User-Agent` с содержимым этих файлов, ASP.NET и заполнял экземпляр `HttpContext.Request.Browser`. При написании ASP.NET Core этот функционал просто не перенесли, но возможно, в будущем Microsoft его добавит.

Поэтому пока, к сожалению, для определения браузера вам придется вручную анализировать содержимое заголовка `User-Agent`:

```
string userAgent = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо kmv! Я почему-то так и предполагал. Они очень много "чего" не перенесли.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите что за тип у вас `HttpContext.Request` -- видимо, проблема в нём.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
    var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
    var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities { Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgent } } };
    var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
    factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), userBrowser);
```